# jquery accordion default expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Working on a project and I am using jQuery's accordion lib. I want all items in the submenu to be expanded by default. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$jsmart(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#yt_sidenav li.level0 > a').addClass ('subhead');
    $('#yt_sidenav li.level0 > a').after ('<a href="#" title="" class="toggle">&nbsp;</a>');    //header 

    ////////////////////
    //$('#yt_sidenav li ul li').has('ul').append( '<span class="more-item-nav">open</span>' );

        var speed=200;
        $('#yt_sidenav li ul li').has('ul').append( '<span class="touch-item">open</span>' );

        $('.touch-item').click(function(){
            $(this).prev().slideToggle(speed);
            $(this).toggleClass('change');
            $(this).prev().prev().toggleClass('parentNote');
        });
    // second simple accordion with special markup
    $jsmart('#yt_sidenav').accordion({
        active: '.active',
        header: '.toggle',      // same header above
        navigation: true,
        event: 'click',
        fillSpace: false,
        autoheight: false,
        alwaysOpen: false, 
        animated: 'easeslide',
        collapsible: false
    }); 

    //check if headerId is set, if so activate that id
    if ($jsmart("#yt_sidenav .level2 .current").parents('.parent').length) {
        var header_element = $jsmart("#yt_sidenav .level2 .current").parents('.parent').children('a.toggle')
        $jsmart('#yt_sidenav').accordion('activate', header_element);
    }           

});
</script>
```

I have looked at the documentation, and have come to the conclusin .index() should be used to expand all by default. But I am lost to where I need to add this code.

Could you please have a look?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the accordion widget is meant to work so that a max of 1 element is open at a time. If you're trying make something that has collapsible sections that can have 0 to all collapsed you could have each section as it's own accordion or have a click event that performs a slide toggle. A little hard to tell exactly what you want without you HTML

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing.  I have 4 panels that I want expanded by default and the user can collapse if they want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jquery collapsible documentation](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible)...
By default, accordions always keep one section open. To allow for all sections to be be collapsible, set the collapsible option to true